# Linux hosted subdomain under Windows hosted domain

Tags: php, hosting, .net

We currently have a website that is hosted on a Windows machine, since the website runs on .NET.

We are planning to build an Intranet portal in Drupal. Is this possible on a subdomain? Would I have to purchase a separate Linux hosting and point the subdomain there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Is this possible on a subdomain?*

Yes.

*Would I have to purchase a separate Linux hosting and point the subdomain there?*

Also yes if you plan to run Drupal on a linux (LAMP) server.

You have short questions I have short answers ;)

Answer (score 1):

Of course you can run Drupal on windows hosting. Why not? Windows hosting support both ASP.NET and also PHP. :) You dont need to purchase Linux hosting anymore